# How to close ReadableStream properly?

Tags: typescript, stream, streaming, openai-api, server-sent-events

I am trying to send Strings I get from `OpenAI` Completion as an SSE-Stream to my client.

I do this:

```
const stream = await openAI.chat.completions.create(completionConfig);  

const body = new ReadableStream({
  async start(controller) {
    for await (const chunk of stream) {
      if (chunk['choices'][0]['delta']['content']) {
        var token = chunk['choices'][0]['delta']['content'];
        controller.enqueue(new TextEncoder().encode("data:" + token + "\r\n\r\n"));
      }
      if (chunk['choices'][0]['finish_reason'] === 'stop') {
        controller.close();
        return;
      }
    }
  },
  cancel() {
    // todo
  },
});
```

I am not sure how to close my stream when I get the last chunk from OpenAi. I can't call `body.cancel()` where I call `controller.close()` as this throws me `event loop error: TypeError: Cannot cancel a locked ReadableStream.`

Does anyone know how to do this properly? Thanks a lot!